# How to remove slash \ before save in database in mysqli?

Tags: php, slash

I am using this script .

```
$category_name = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'category', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$db->query("INSERT INTO `category` (name,sort) VALUES ('$category','0') ");
```

But if end of value of **$_GET['category']** be slash fo e.g `hello \`   OR `\`  OR `\ hello \` All of value dosnt save and query dosn't insert .

It's not imprtant to me save slash in database . I want just save in database whithout \ for e.g (Hello \ ) save (Hello). There are any filter_input for this ?

Comment: Ever heard of SQL escaping or parameter binding?

Comment: No  i don't @mario .

Comment: See also [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/60496)

Comment: It's not imprtant to me save slash in database . I want just save in database whithout \ for e.g (Hello \ ) save (Hello). There are any filter_input for this ?@mario

Comment: That's not what the filter_* functions are for.

Comment: I edit this question please remove This question already has an answer here ..... becuse its not my question . @mario

Comment: Yep, it's not your question. It's your answer though. Whether you bother to read it or not.

Comment: @mario yes i read it but it's not my answer to . please remove :) please

Comment: Then see the long list of results on [how to remove a backslash](https://www.google.de/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+php+remove+backslash+from+string)